# Calculate running total while cells remain the same

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on creating a macro that creates a running total based on criteria in a neighboring column. I'm able to do it with a combination of formulas but I would like to be able to do it in VBA. The code I have thus far can handle it with a few rows, but not more than 4.

```
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("O1") = ""

    If LastRow1 = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Closed-Won for " & RepName
        ElseIf LastRow1 = 2 Then
            .Cells(2, LastColumn + 1).Formula = "=F2"
        ElseIf LastRow = 3 Then
            k = 0
            For k = 3 To LastRow1
            .Cells(k, LastColumn + 2).Value = Month(Worksheets(RepName.Text).Cells(k, 8))
            Next k
            .Cells(3, LastColumn + 1).Formula = "=F3+O2"
        ElseIf LastRow1 = 4 Then
            .Cells(2, LastColumn + 1).Value = .Cells(2, 6).Value
            .Cells(3, LastColumn + 1).Formula = "=F3+O2"
            .Cells(4, LastColumn + 1).Formula = "=F4+O3"
        ElseIf LastRow1 > 4 Then
            .Cells(2, LastColumn + 1).Value = .Cells(2, 6).Value
            .Cells(3, LastColumn + 1).Formula = "=F3+O2"
            Call Q1
        Else: 'do nothing
    End If
```

(This is the snippet of code that handles that particular action) I think there must be a better way to do this but I am not sure what it is. Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image: Example of what the final product should look like]

Comment: What's your question? Does it work as you like, you're just looking for tips on making it more efficient? Or are you asking how to do more rows? Also, why can't you do more than 4 rows, do you get errors? Does it time out?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use VBA for this? It can be accomplished with a single formula very easily. `=SUMIF($B$2:B2,B2,$A$2:A2)` in cell C2 copied down will do it.

Comment: I usually just do a quick and dirty addition. For example, C4 would be `=A4`, then C5 would be `=C4 + A5`, C6 would be `=C5 + A6`...etc.

Comment: @Comintern That works, but it requires you to manually change the formula for each criteria value, if you had a sheet with thousands of rows, that would get extremely tedious. The answer by chris neilsen allows you to use a single formula for an unlimited number of categories.

Answer (score 2):

The formula to use in cell C2 is

```
=IF(B2=B1,C1+A2,A2)
```

and copy down as far as required

The code to create that formula (if you must) is (Excel will take care of updating the cell references)

```
Sub Demo()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2)
        rng.Formula = "=IF(B2=B1,C1+A2,A2)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is actually a better formula to use than `SUMIF` because it will scale better if your dataset is very large. This formula only ever references the values in 4 cells whereas doing it with `SUMIF` will cause the number of cells referenced by the formula to constantly grow.

Comment: @DavidP actually, your `SumIf` formula doesn't do what the OP requested.  There are repeated values in Criteria column, OP want to restart the sum on each block (see row 23, your formula would give 36 for that row)

Comment: Good catch. I guess I didn't actually look closely enough to see that they had repeating criteria. It would only work if you had non-repeating criteria, or wanted to get a running total for criteria in non-contiguous groups.